# using data from txt file to answer questions in python

Tags: python

```
a01:01-24-2011:s1 
a03:01-24-2011:s2 
a02:01-24-2011:s2 
a03:02-02-2011:s2 
a03:03-02-2011:s1 
a02:04-19-2011:s2 
a01:05-14-2011:s2 
a02:06-11-2011:s2 
a03:07-12-2011:s1 
a01:08-19-2011:s1 
a03:09-19-2011:s1 
a03:10-19-2011:s2 
a03:11-19-2011:s1 
a03:12-19-2011:s2
```

format  is animalid:date:location

## the above is that data that i have saved in a txt file named animallog2.txt. I have imported this into my code.I want to use the above to answer a few questions.

So far this is the code that I have

```
def main():
    fname = input("Enter name of file: ")
    with open(fname) as inf:
          animalnames, dates, locations = zip(*[line.strip().split(':') for line in inf])

d = {}
for animalname, loc in zip(animalnames, locations):
    d.setdefault(animalname, []).append(loc)  

print("Animal ID","Location1","Location2")       
for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, end='\t')                       #To print table of the data
    print(v.count('s1'), end='\t')
    print(v.count('s2'))        
print("================================================================================================================")
```

the table that I have is

```
Animal ID Location1 Location2
a01        2    1
a02        0    3
```

## a03        4        4

could someone help as to how i can use all the above to answer the questions:

1)animals that visited both stations atleast 4 times   #answer is a03

2)total number of visits for each animal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already done most of the work, this will get your answers:

1)

```
for k, v in d.items():
    if v.count('s1')>=4 and v.count('s2')>=4:
        print k
```

2)

```
for k, v in d.items():
    print k, v.count('s1')+v.count('s2')
```